# React JSON Array issue

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, typescript

I have an array in react like below

```
[
  {
    year: 2014
    field: "Coal"
    value: 100
  },
  {
    year: 2014
    field: "power"
    value: 200
  }, {
    year: 2014
    field: "oil"
    value: 20
  },
  {
    year: 2014
    field: "air"
    value: 33
  }
]
```

Is there any possible way to convert this array on the basis of a common property. In this it is Year.And get the result like below

```
{
    year: 2014,
    coal:100,
    power:200
    air: 33,
    oil: 20
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```js
let arr = [
    {year: 2014, field: 'Coal', value: 100 },
    {year: 2014, field: 'power', value: 200},
    {year: 2014, field: 'oil', value: 20},
    {year: 2014, field: 'air', value: 33},
    {year: 2015, field: 'Coal', value: 101},
    {year: 2015, field: 'power', value: 202},
    {year: 2015, field: 'oil', value: 23},
    {year: 2015, field: 'air', value: 33}
];
                 
arr = arr.reduce((result, e) => {
    (result[e.year] = result[e.year] || {})[e.field] = e.value;
    return result;
}, {});
                 
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [{
  year: 2014,
  field: "Coal",
  value: 100
}, {
  year: 2014,
  field: "power",
  value: 200
}, {
  year: 2014,
  field: "oil",
  value: 20
}, {
  year: 2014,
  field: "air",
  value: 33
}];

const resObj = {};

arr.forEach((obj) => {
    resObj.year = obj.year;
  resObj[obj.field] = obj.value;
});

console.log(resObj);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here a solution with a reduce. It's not the cleanest but it works. If you already have something like [immer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immer) in your project it could be of hlp.

```
type Energies = 'coal' | 'power' | 'oil' | 'air'
type RawEntry = {
  year: number,
  field: Energies
  value: number
}
type ByYearEntry = {
  year: number
  [key: string]: number
}

const data2014: RawEntry[] = [
  { year: 2014, field: 'coal', value: 100 },
  { year: 2014, field: 'power', value: 200 },
  { year: 2015, field: 'coal', value: 1000 },
  { year: 2015, field: 'power', value: 2000 },
]

function format(data: RawEntry[]) {
  return data.reduce((acc, { year, field, value }) => {
    const yearData = acc.find(d => d.year === year)
    if (yearData) {
      yearData[field] = value
      return acc
    }
    acc.push({ year, [field]: value })
    return acc
  }, [] as ByYearEntry[])
}

console.log(format(data2014))
```

PS: Instead of your proposed data structure, you could go for something like

```js
{
  2014: {
    coal: 100,
    power: 100,
  },
}
```

Is it something you could consider? I guess it depends on whaat you want to do with the data after.